# How to get the begin date by tri-annual period (the year is devided into 3 parts)

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the beginning date of each one third part of year, when I give a date the return must be the first day (date) of this one-third part.

Example: if the parameter is '1-april-2023' the return must be '1-jan-2023'

if the parameter is '1-june-2023' the return must be '1-may-2023'

and so on

Comment: So what is stopping you from achieve this task? What is the difficulty you are having? What were your attempts? Why aren't they working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do some date math by adding 4 months times the (month-1)/4 to the beginning of the year.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetThirdOfYear(@d date)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT Third = DATEADD(MONTH, 
      4*((MONTH(@d)-1)/4), 
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d),1,1))
  );
```

Sample usage, given a table called `Events` with a column called `EventDate`:

```
SELECT e.EventDate, f.Third
FROM dbo.Events AS e
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetThirdOfYear(e.EventDate) AS f;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aj5lt5Ka) (and [how I got there](https://dbfiddle.uk/03W4zW4A)).